# Como mostrar el dia actual en label con Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando que un *label* me muestre el texto: **"Hoy" + dia de la semana que estamos**, el código que implemente es:

```
self.label.setText("Hoy"+datetime.date.today())
```

Pero al correr el programa me da error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

---

Leyendo un poco me percate que lo unico que tenia que hacer era concatenar y llevar de *int* a *str* quedaria asi:

```
fecha = datatime.data.today()

self.label.settext("Hoy es" + srt(fecha):)
```

y la salida queda:

```
Hoy 2020/10/09
```

por lo que todavia necesito que sea el dia actual asi que sigo necesitando ayuda gracias.

Comment: `self.label.setText("Hoy"+str(datetime.date.today()))` intenta

Comment: gracias bro, ya me di cuenta pero me sale la fecha pero necesito el dia

Answer (score 0):

Creo que buscas esto:

```
from datetime import datetime as date
date.today().strftime("%A")
```

Comment: sería bueno explicar un poco la respuesta, indicando por ejemplo que el parámetro %A significa el día de la semana